# Mongodb collections to data frames

Tags: r, mongodb

I have a MongoDB database "borlette" which I'm trying to turn multiple
collections into data frames.
I tried with RMongo still it is limited to 1000 rows which is a problem,
with the following code:

```
library(RMongo)

mongo <- mongoDbConnect("borlette")
dbShowCollections(mongo)
# nb of owners : 27 documents
df_owners <- dbGetQuery(mongo, "owners", "{}")
# nb of banks : 127
df_banks <- dbGetQuery(mongo, "banks", "{}")
# nb of sellings : 55 236 
df_sellings <- dbGetQuery(mongo, "sellings", "{}")
# nb of tickets : 1 523 005
df_tickets <- dbGetQuery(mongo, "tickets", "{}")

head(results, 10)
dim(df_tickets)

dbDisconnect(mongo)
```

I tried with the "rmongodb" solution as well from this link [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22445419/transfer-large-mongodb-collections-to-data-frame-in-r-with-rmongodb-and-plyr)
but it seems to not working properly with NoSQL (multiple error messages).

Comment: `rmongodb` is no longer supported and [no longer on CRAN](https://github.com/dselivanov/rmongodb/issues/96)

Answer (score 0):

The package `mongolite` returns your queries into data.frames for you

```
library(mongolite)

mongo <- mongo(collection = "owners", db = "borlette", url = "mongodb://localhost")
df_owners <- mongo$find() ## will return everything from 'owners'

rm(mongo); gc()  ## clean up
```