# How do I get a dataframe representation of a collection from mongdb in R

Tags: r, mongodb, dataframe

I am trying to retrieve an entire collection from mongodb and then convert it into a dataframe in R. 
The question was answered here

[Transfer large MongoDB collections to data.frame in R with rmongodb and plyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22445419/transfer-large-mongodb-collections-to-data-frame-in-r-with-rmongodb-and-plyr)

But the package they are using does not seem to be available anymore so I am trying to figure out how I would accomplish this with mongolite (or another package of your suggestion).

Comment: You could also try `mongolite`, which is actively maintained: https://github.com/jeroen/mongolite

Comment: The `rmongodb` and `RMongo` packages were removed from CRAN a few years ago because they were no longer actively updated and not compatible with modern versions of MongoDB. `mongolite` is currently the only actively maintained R driver. `mongolite`'s `find()` method automatically returns a data frame; I suggest trying the driver and editing your question to include the R code you tried if you are unable to get this to work.